# Console Application doesn't exit when compiled using Multi-Threaded (/MT) configuration

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, visual-studio-2013, console-application

I wrote the following code and used Visual Studio 2013 to build my .exe

```
#include <windows.h>   
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <iostream>   
#include <string>   
#include <unistd.h>   

DWORD WINAPI reader(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    std::string str;
    std::cout << "inside reader" << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
   HANDLE hThreadR;
   DWORD dwThreadId, dwThrdParam = 1;
   int threadStatus;
   bool terminateThreadStatus;

   hThreadR = CreateThread(NULL, 0, reader, 0, 0, &dwThreadId);
   threadStatus = WaitForSingleObject(hThreadR, 10000);
   if (threadStatus == 258)
   {
        terminateThreadStatus = TerminateThread(hThreadR, 0);
        std::cout << "terminateThreadStatus: " << terminateThreadStatus << std::endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The problem that I am facing is the following:

If I build the .exe using the `Multi-Threaded DLL(/MD)
(PROJECT->ConsoleApplication Property Pages->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Code Generation->Multi-Threaded DLL(/MD))` and there is nothing received in stdin after 10 secs, thread times out and is terminated and program closes. This is the desired behavior.

If I build the .exe using the `Multi-Threaded (/MT)
(PROJECT->ConsoleApplication Property Pages->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Code Generation->Multi-Threaded DLL(/MT))` and there is nothing received in stdin after 10 secs, thread times out and is terminated but program remains open.

I wanted to build the .exe using Multi-Threaded (/MT) in order to avoid error...

> The program can't start because MSVCP120.dll is missing from your computer" when .exe runs to a computer that doesn't have the MSVCP120.dll.

Any idea what causes the above described behavior?

Comment: What sayeth the debugger?

Comment: Standard deadlock, calling TerminateThread() is *dangerous*.  You cannot use the console anymore after you killed it.  Under the hood, std::getline() acquired a lock to ensure that no other thread can use the console at the same time.  That lock didn't get reset.  There isn't any point in terminating the thread at all, the OS will take care of it automatically when your main() function returns.

Comment: And that's pretty much what debugger shows. Main is hung inside `_lock` called from `__endstdio`.

Comment: My main question is why the configuration mode changes program behavior, I mean why program is not terminated when build using /MT but is terminated when usign /MD?

Comment: The statically linked library does things differently from the DLL. Why? Different code. Why different code? possibly newer DLL.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I don't  agree with you totally, if you create a second thread inside the main() program e.g. a writer thread that sends to stdout, you will see the message that writer thread sends in the console while reader waits for stdin.

Comment: Ah, good to hear that you don't have a real problem.

Comment: Same behaviour with and without the `TerminateThread`, but Hans's point about the lock on cin is correct.

Comment: As mentioned in the question my issue is that I want to build the .exe using static library link and get the behavior of dynamic library link (which is that main program closes as soon as it finishes).

Comment: Don't have a good solution for you. You need to end the `std::getline(std::cin, str);` before the program will exit.

Comment: Poking at this with VS2010 you can also force the same behaviour with `fclose(stdin)`, so you can't even pull the supercheese maneuver of closing the file descriptor to end the blocking read.

Comment: How can I close `std::getline(std::cin, str);` so that the main program exits?

Comment: Beside everything else, NEVER use CreateThread to start C++ threads in Windows. Use `std::thread`, or, if you are version impaired, use `_beginthreadex`

Comment: Undefined behaviour.  It is only pure chance that at the moment it works with the dynamically linked runtime but not the statically linked runtime.   Next week it might be the other way around.

Comment: Any ideas how I can safely exit main program if I don't receive input after ten secs?

Comment: Well in fact the behavior is very well defined and there should be no difference between static or dynamic linking. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx) `If the target thread is the last thread of a process when this function is called, the thread's process is also terminated.`. If only it were the only inconsistency between microsoft's documentation and the real world.